# Earning money with Smoke on the Water

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I Purchased Smoke on the Water (in Story Mode) and had read I would receive a text sometime soon after.  I have not received  anything and it's been just over a week. There is no "P" icon on map, no emails, and no text. I saw absolutely nothing.  Did I just waste $204,000.00?  All other businesses are earning weekly!
Please help.